# Request failed with status code 429 Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to parse lots of data from external API endpoint to my Database, I keep getting error 429.

I've tried timeout and sleep lib but it doesn't work for some reason.

Here is the code :

```js
async function(req, res) {
    console.log("usa sam");
    try {
        let count = await Subjekti.estimatedDocumentCount();
        let response = await axios.get(`x.com/?offset=${count}&limit=5000`, {
            timeout: 5800,
            headers: {
                "Key": "x"
            }
        });
        const subjects = response.data;
        for (let subject of subjects) {
            let companyDetails = await axios.get(`https://x.com=${subject.mbs}&expand_relations=true`, {
                headers: {
                    "Key": "x"
                }
            });
            await Subjekti({
                mbs: subject.mbs,
                sud_id_nadlezan: subject.sud_id_nadlezan,
                sud_id_sluzba: subject.sud_id_sluzba,
                oib: subject.oib,
                ino_podruznica: subject.ino_podruznica,
                stecajna_masa: subject.stecajna_masa,
                datum_osnivanja: subject.datum_osnivanja,
                postupak: subject.postupak,
                likvidacijska_masa: subject.likvidacijska_masa,
                skracene_tvrtke: companyDetails.data.skracene_tvrtke && companyDetails.data.skracene_tvrtke.length > 0 ? companyDetails.data.skracene_tvrtke[0].ime : null,
                ulica: companyDetails.data.sjedista && companyDetails.data.sjedista.length > 0 ? companyDetails.data.sjedista[0].ulica : null,
                kucni_broj: companyDetails.data.sjedista && companyDetails.data.sjedista.length > 0 ? companyDetails.data.sjedista[0].kucni_broj : null,
                naziv_naselja: companyDetails.data.sjedista && companyDetails.data.sjedista.length > 0 ? companyDetails.data.sjedista[0].naziv_naselja : null,
                naziv_zupanije: companyDetails.data.sjedista && companyDetails.data.sjedista.length > 0 ? companyDetails.data.sjedista[0].naziv_zupanije : null,
            }).save();
            console.log("spremija i cekam");

        }
    } catch (err) {
        //Baci error 500...
        return apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res, err);
    }
}
```

Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found out solution:

await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

Hope it helps someone and save you time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using debounce approach in this case to avoid sending too many requests.

see an example here : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Comment: Please include the solution in your answer instead of only linking to an external site. The link might break in the future rendering your solution unusable for future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending too many requests, and you get ratelimited.

You should change your logic to allow more data to be sent and retrieved with a single request, or delaying most part of your requests to a later stage.

To delay request using axios interceptors, take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52258937/7629020

Comment: Could you hint  me up  ( with part of code )what to do , i am clueless after so much hours spent trying .But please notice evry request it has it own ID. ${subject.mbs}

Comment: It's pretty hard without knowing what you want to achieve. But let say want to take the users down from a company db. The company as >10.000 users. 

Instead of asking for all the users, and then for the detail of a single users all in the same "page", you should first ask for the datas of all users (like, name and id), then when the user click on the id, you can do the second request to load the specific user.

Comment: Well im trying to parse data from external database to mine database thats all.

Comment: Take a look at this question here on how you can delay requests and (hopefully) not get rate-limited. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52258937/7629020

Comment: Hey, yeah ive tryed something similar including few libs, for some reason it doesnt want to stop, or if it stops, it stops forever.